# cut not cutting the columns when used with pipe

Tags: linux, command-line

I'm trying to grep and cut using pipes.
file:

```
c1 c2
e1 e2
e3 e4
```

this file has space-separated values, but when I execute

`cut -f2 -d' ' | grep "e2" example.csv`
output is `e1 e2`

the output should be `e2` but I'm not sure if the `cut` takes input in some other format, in the man pages it says that file name if unspecified then input would be taken.

Answer (score 3):

You have it backwards. The output of `cut` must be sent to `grep`.

```
cut -f2 -d' ' example.csv | grep e2
```

Otherwise, `grep` operates on the file, not on its input, and `cut` operates on the standard input, which is coming from the outer context, probably your keyboard?

The pipeline takes the output of the *left hand side* command and connects it to the input of the *right hand side* one, not the other way round. The left hand side command doesn't know what the arguments of the right hand side command are (and vice versa).

Answer (score 1):

Use your input file as an argument to `cut`:

```
cut -f2 -d' ' example.csv | grep "e2"
```